# Minimum office space in European Union legislation

Tags: offices, law, office-layout, europe

Is there an European Union law that defines the minimum office space a desk  employee (i.e. people that use a desk and computer) should have ?

I found some laws in Germany and UK, but nothing at EU-level. Are there any EU rules / minimum requirements for this ?

Comment: What about [this?](https://oshwiki.eu/wiki/Workplace_minimum_requirements_and_EU_OSH_legislation)

Comment: That page references some annexes that are not there.

Comment: Best thing I could find is this: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:01989L0654-20070627 (Article 15) but it does not state any minimum requirements.

Comment: I believe this shouldn't need a lawyer to answer so shouldn't be closed as legal advice, however it has had one vote for that.

The meta states [this](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1861/52713) on legal advice,

However, you may find you'll get a better response over at the [Law stack exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Draken such question may be answerable from a HR, it makes it on topic so. An HR would have to know the minimum space, however it may not bother if it comes from EU or his country.

Comment: @Walfrat I fully agree, hence my comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [EU regulation 1989/654/EEC Annex 1](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:01989L0654-20070627&from=EN) states this:

> 15. Room dimensions and air space in rooms — freedom of movement at the workstation
>
>     - (15.1) Workrooms must have sufficient surface area, height and air space to allow workers to perform their work without risk to their
>         safety, health or well-being.
>     - (15.2) The dimensions of the free unoccupied area at the workstation must be calculated to allow workers sufficient freedom of movement to
>         perform their work. If this is not possible for reasons specific to
>         the ►C1 workstation ◄, the worker must be provided with sufficient
>         freedom of movement near his workstation

So it's all very vague which allows independent countries (Or even companies) to be able to define what is considered *sufficient freedom of movement to perform their work*

The EU generally does this on purpose so to not enforce specificities, but allow each country to define it's own definition of the rule:

> A regulation shall have general application. It shall be binding in
>   its entirety and directly applicable in all Member States.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulation_(European_Union))

---

So to answer your question, **no the EU regulation does not define a minimum size for an office space.** It just implies it should be suitable for the work being carried out in that space.

Answer (score 0):

No EU regulations are devolved to countries to implement eg TUPE is quite different from country to country - you would need to check locally in the country concerned.